# Set Scanner to Read Only QR Code and Ignore other type of BarCodes

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I am using this library to scan QR Codes. This library is very simple but I am having a hard time trying to figure out on making it to responds only to QR Codes.

It uses ZXing behind it.

[CamView](https://github.com/LivotovLabs/CamView)

```
    //MARK - scannerLiveView
    ZXDecoder decoder=new ZXDecoder();
    decoder.setScanAreaPercent(0.5);

    ScannerLiveView scannerLiveView = (ScannerLiveView) findViewById(R.id.scannerLiveView);
    scannerLiveView.setDecoder(decoder);
```

Here is how I did it. But the problem is that it responds to all kind of bar codes. I would like to have it responds on QR Codes only.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ZXDecoder is hardcoded to scan all possible formats. https://github.com/LivotovLabs/CamView/blob/53e3112592980754628bab2b770ed16900b9c407/CAMView/src/main/java/eu/livotov/labs/android/camview/scanner/decoder/zxing/ZXDecoder.java. You could create a new class QRDecoder which should look pretty much the same as ZXDecoder but instead of creating MultiFormatReader it should create [QRCodeReader](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader.java)